Getting error on Azure function as 1 functions found (Custom) 0 functions loaded
Having an issue with azure timer trigger v2 as having error
enter image description here
1 functions found (Custom) 
0 functions loaded 

any idea how to fix it? I am having same issue as getting this error in logs after deployment.
also function name is not listed in overview page .
enter image description here
Any idea how to fix it

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

It is hard to tell why you are facing this issue without more details on the deployment approach you have taken. The issue is most likely caused by a incorrect directory upload during the deployment.
If you have used a Zip deploy, ensure you have zipped the contents of the project root directory and not the root directory itself. Deploying the function app using Visual Studio code or Visual Studio uses this approach by default in the backend.
If you continue facing this issue by deploying through a tool, try deploying the function app using Azure Core Tools CLI using the following command
func azure functionapp publish <FunctionAppName>

Refer to Deployment methods to get more information on different approaches possible to deploy an Azure function.
Share your deployment log if you run into additional issues.
